# Is it possible to set s3 bucket name on API call when uploading to inkfilepicker?

Tags: filepicker, filepicker.io

So instead of going to the s3 page to set the s3 credentials. It isn't possible to call it to the API? for example on the json option

```
filepicker.pickAndStore({
    location: 'S3',
    bucket: '{bucketname}', //set here instead on the s3 settings page
    path: '/uploadpath/file.ext',
    access: 'public'
}, success function(InkBlob){
    console.log(InkBlob);
});
```

Or if this really isn't possible. Does it a good idea to include it for future use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want use different buckets you need to create two different filepicker apps that will use different buckets. Because when we are setting up s3 for an app we should fill "S3 Access Key ID", "Secret key" and "S3 bucket". Looks like only those settings for s3 storage are used